# Python - ImportError: No module named servo

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm using Raspberry PI for my robotic project. I got this error when try run this code into my raspberry PI through terminal.

```
#servo_example.py
import servo
servo.servo_setup()
#0 - 180 degrees only!
servo.servo_set_deg(145)
servo.servo_cleanup()
```

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "servo_example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import servo
ImportError: No module named servo
```

Why I got this error message? How I can fix it?

Comment: Is `servo` installed?

Comment: how to install servo?

Comment: Did you try [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)?  You have enough rep on this site that I am surprised that when your program complained that your module didn't exist your first thought wasn't "is this installed?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have named your script `servo.py`. This means that when you `import servo`, you are importing your own script. It doesn't have a function named `servo_setup` so you get an error. You can't import the system's `servo.py` while your own script is named `servo.py`. Solution: name your script something else.

Comment: Please don't do that. My answer is now not an answer to your question.